# Concavity of a simple objective function

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, non-convex-optimization

I have a maximization problem with the following objective function
$$
f= \log\left(\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\right)+\log\left(1-\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{x_i}{y_i}\right).
$$
I would like to show that $f$ is concave in general. It is when $n=1$ since then
$$
f=\log\left(x-\frac{x^2}{y} \right)
$$
and $x^2/y$ is convex. Can we generalize this result to $n\geq 2$?

Comment: My prior comment was (incorrectly) for the function $f(x,y) = \log(\sum_i x_i - \sum_i \frac{x_i^2}{y_i})$, which is not what is asked.

Comment: The function asked does not look concave for $n=2$.  What if you try $(x_1,x_2)=(.1,2)$, $(\tilde{x}_1,\tilde{x}_2)=(1,.1)$, $(y_1,y_2)=(10,5)$, $(\tilde{y}_1,\tilde{y}_2)=(27,2.1)$.  I get $$ f\left(\frac{1}{2}(x,y) + \frac{1}{2}(\tilde{x}, \tilde{y})\right) < \frac{1}{2}f(x,y) + \frac{1}{2}f(\tilde{x},\tilde{y})$$

Comment: Thanks @Michael. I just came to the same conclusion by computing the eigenvalues of the Hessian for a few points. Back to the drawing board!